# Спецификатор и квалификатор

Tags: c++

В чём разница между спецификатором и квалификатором?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Квалификаторы квалифицируют спецификаторы.:)

Имеется два квалификатора: это `const` и `volatile`, которые в совокупности называются cv-квалификаторами.

Квалификаторы сами по себе не определяют тип. Это спецификаторы, которые определяют тип объектов. А квалификаторы далее квалифицируют указанный тип уже как `const`, `volatile` или `const volatile`. То есть чтобы применить квалификатор тип объекта, функции или иной сущности должен быть уже определен с помощью спецификаторов. То есть вы можете, например, сказать, что данный целочисленный тип (или объект целочисленного типа) является константным.